# Draggable Mouse Cursor

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How do I get the **mouse cursor** to become `SystemMouseCursors.grabbing` while a draggable is mid-flight?

This is what I have so far.

```
return Draggable(
      data: data,
      onDragCompleted: () {
        setState(() {
          data = widget.create();
        });
      },
      child: MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.grab,
        child: child: child,
      ),
      childWhenDragging: MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.grabbing,
        child: child,
      ),
      feedback: MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.grabbing,
        child: child,
      )
    );
```

With this the cursor acts correctly when hovering and not dragging `(SystemMouseCursors.grab)` and if you don't move your mouse from the origin but grab (`SystemMouseCursors.grabbing`).

However as soon as you drag it away from the origin it goes straight back to the `SystemMouseCursors.basic`.

How do I get the cursor to be `SystemMouseCursors.grabbing` throughout the draggable's flight?

Comment: I opened an issue related to this problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92083

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I just set `ignoringFeedbackPointer: false` in the `Draggable` widget and it worked.